# How can I check if a datetime is valid in PHP as per time jumps that occur for daylight savings time?

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, mariadb, dst

Today, I was inserting some data into a MariaDB 10.4.11 DB from a Laravel 6.9.0 seeder using the Eloquent `insert` method of various models.

Some of the inserts failed because of some particular `created_at` and `updated_at` datetimes that I attempted to insert. One of the datetimes was the following:

```
2018-03-11 02:57:51
```

At first, I couldn't tell why this datetime wouldn't insert, as it looked completely innocuous, but after scratching my head for a bit, I realized that this was an invalid datetime because of the daylight savings time jump that occurs in America (and perhaps other places in the world) every spring.

Specifically, early in the morning of Sunday, March 11, 2018, when the clocks in America reached 2 AM, they instantly jumped to 3 AM in order to shift for daylight savings time. As such, the datetime `2018-03-11 02:57:51` is invalid.

I happen to be in the Eastern timezone in America, so I not sure if that made a difference when I attempted the insert, but basically, the insert would fail every time because of that datetime.

As such, I was trying to figure out if there was a way to check if a datetime is a valid datetime as per whether it falls within a skipped hour or not due to the daylight savings time jump in the spring.

Is there any way to do that in PHP? And to that, if I do find a datetime that's invalid, what should I do with it? Should I add an hour to the datetime so that it's valid and then insert it into the DB? Thanks.

Comment: Eloqunet `insert()` doesn't fill the `created_at` field though, no? I usually do `now()` to refer to Carbon.

Comment: Timezones are for humans only. Store/compute everything in UTC, apply timezones for display purposes only.

Comment: I'm adding the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields manually in this case because this is in a seeder in which I'm importing data from a table in another DB that already has those fields set. Also, in Laravel, I tried setting the timezone to `UTC`, but still had the same issue.

Comment: How are you generating the values? Ie show us your code.

Comment: I'm not generating the values at all. I'm literally pulling the dates as is from another DB. They're in the DB just like that. How they got in there like that, I don't know, but that's how they're in there.

Comment: Yes, that seems to resolve my issue. Thank you.

Comment: Don't use `DATETIME`, use `TIMESTAMP`.